# Cocos2D - Layer background color not changing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I want to integrate cocos2d in one of my view. So, I have a normal view controller(`MapEditorViewController`) and a view, in my view controller, (I created a `IBOutlet UIView *openGLView`) in which I want cocos2d to be in. In my view controller, I have a method setupCocos2D :

```
- (void)setupCocos2D {
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:self.openGLView.bounds
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                        ];
    glView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.openGLView insertSubview:glView atIndex:0];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setOpenGLView:glView];
    CCScene *scene = [HelloWorldLayer scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene];
}
```

`setupCocos2D` is called in `viewDidLoad` of the class `MapEditorViewController`.

I have a layer (`HelloWorldLayer`), which is basically the code in the tutorial of http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial

```
// Helper class method that creates a Scene with the HelloWorldLayer as the only child.
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

- (void) addMonster {

    CCSprite * monster = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"backbutton.png"];

    // Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    int minY = monster.contentSize.height / 2;
    int maxY = winSize.height - monster.contentSize.height/2;
    int rangeY = maxY - minY;
    int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

    // Create the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
    // and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
    monster.position = ccp(winSize.width + monster.contentSize.width/2, actualY);
    [self addChild:monster];

    // Determine speed of the monster
    int minDuration = 2.0;
    int maxDuration = 4.0;
    int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

    // Create the actions
    CCMoveTo * actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                                position:ccp(-monster.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
    CCCallBlockN * actionMoveDone = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
        [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }];
    [monster runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
    if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255,0,255,255)]) ) {

        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"carteIntrouvable.png"];
        player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:player];


        [self setIsTouchEnabled:YES];

        [self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:1.0];

            }
    return self;
}

-(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
    [self addMonster];
}
```

Now, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, the layer appears but it is **black**, even though I change the line `initWithColor` in `-(id) init`.

**How can I change the layer's background color, because the code works if I don't integrate cocos2d with UIKit... ?**

Comment: is your init being called ?

Comment: yes, I verified that.

Comment: Did you change the HelloWorldLayer to subclass CCLayerColor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternative Solution: Add CCLayerColor to base layer.

```
-(void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    ccColor4B color = {255,255,0,255};
    CCLayerColor *colorLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:color];
    [self addChild:colorLayer z:LAST_LAYER_PLUS_1];
}
```

Comment: put this function inside onEnter method...then it should work...make sure you put right z-orering..